# In react js i create a todo app but when i am doing todo-delete it by default delete the first item why?

Tags: reactjs

**In react js i create a todo app but when i am doing todo-delete it by default delete the first item why?In react js i create a todo app but when i am doing todo-delete it by default delete the first item why?In react js i create a todo app but when i am doing todo-delete it by default delete the first item why?**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
const Todo = () => {
const [inputData, setInputData] = useState("");

const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

const addItem = (e) => {
let pattern = /\s/g.test(inputData);
// This pattern check empty space and InputData is checking null
if (pattern === false && inputData !== "") {
setItems([...items, inputData]);
setInputData("");
}
setInputData("");
};
// delete items
const deleteItem = (idx) => {
// console.log(idx);
let temp = [...items];
//  console.log(temp);
temp.splice(idx, 1);
setItems(temp);
};
// done items
// const doneItem = (idx) => {};

return (
<>
<div className="container">
<h1 className="bg-dark text-white">Todo App</h1>
<div className="d-flex p-2 justify-content-between">
<input
type="text"
className="form-control"
placeholder="Add Your New Todo"
value={inputData}
onChange={(e) => {
setInputData(e.target.value);
//  console.log(e);
// console.log(e.nativeEvent.data);
}}
/>
<button className="btn btn-dark m-1" onClick={addItem}>
+
</button>
</div>
{items.map((element, idx) => {
console.log(element);
console.log(idx);
return (
<div
className="d-flex justify-content-between p-2  bg-dark text-white"
key={idx}
>
<h4>{element}</h4>

<button
className="btn btn-danger"
onClick={(idx) => {
deleteItem(idx);
}}
>
X
</button>
{/* <button onClick={() => doneItem(idx)}>-</button> */}
</div>
);
})}
</div>
</>
);
};

export default Todo;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem starts in this code.

```
<button
  className="btn btn-danger"
  onClick={(idx) => { // problem starts here 
    deleteItem(idx);
  }}
>
  X
</button>;
```

You are already using `idx` as an index for your values in the `map` function. Button basically gives you the `event` and you are representing the same variable. Just remove that variable from the button onClick event and everything works fine.

Attached a sandbox

[image: Edit empty-surf-kuwd5d]

Comment: I got it... but my question is in some cases we pass event as a parameter but here we are not passing the idx why?

Comment: You are removing the item from the list based on the index. If you define `idx` in `onClick`, the `idx` will return the event itself. Use a different variable like `onClick={(event) => { deleteItem(idx);}}`. Now you can use `event` and can be passed to any function.